# Преобразовать массив из другого массива

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста как из этого массива

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [PODGRUP_ID] => 1012789
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [PODGRUP_ID] => 2001289
                )
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [PODGRUP_ID] => 2001291
                )
        )
)
```

получить такой массив

```
Array(1012789,2001289,2001291)
```

Comment: У цикле. Все преобразования массивов делаются в цикле.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = array_column(array_column($array, 0), 'PODGRUP_ID')
```

При условии, что структура именно такая и что в первом элементе каждого массива именно `[PODGRUP_ID] => ...`.

---

Хотя уверен, что изначально данные можно нормально выбрать из БД (наверняка это оттуда)